# SandboxPostCopy callout throws UnexpectedException

Tags: callout, unexpectedexception, sandboxpostcopy

When I attempt to perform a callout from a `SandboxPostCopy` class when creating a sandbox, it throws the following `UnexpectedException`:

```
System.UnexpectedException: Attempt to release db connection when not allowed
```

This is the debug log I find in the newly created sandbox:

```
07:07:25.0 (34108845)|CALLOUT_REQUEST|53.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;NBA,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
07:51:43.0 (551744)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|005###########|autoproc@00d###############|(GMT-08:00) Pacific Standard Time (America/Los_Angeles)|GMT-08:00
07:51:43.0 (13475162)|CALLOUT_REQUEST|[6]|System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://example.com, Method=GET]
07:51:43.0 (34738082)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[6]|System.UnexpectedException: Attempt to release db connection when not allowed
Justification: RTCJustification4269433820
```

My class is:

```
global class MySandboxPostCopy implements SandboxPostCopy {
    global void runApexClass(SandboxContext context) {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://example.com');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        new Http().send(req);
    }
}
```

When I run it from the developer console using the following, it succeeds:

```
new MySandboxPostCopy().runApexClass(null);
```

A remote site setting exists for `https://example.com`. I have successfully performed callouts from `SandboxPostCopy` classes in the past, but those classes are now failing despite being unchanged. I do not know when they started failing. Any ideas as to what the issue could be?

Comment: Aside from quarterly releases,  SF frequently rolls out patches to orgs, one of them might be causing this. Open a case with SF support.

Comment: I opened a case and a known issue was created https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002K6YPQA0